# Splitting large tar file into multiple tar files

Tags: linux, split, tar

I have a tar file which is 3.1 TB(TeraByte)

File name - Testfile.tar

I would like to split this tar file into 2 parts - Testfil1.tar and Testfile2.tar

**I tried the following so far**
split -b 1T Testfile.tar "Testfile.tar"

What i get is Testfile.taraa(what is "aa")

And i just stopped my command. I also noticed that the output **Testfile.taraa** doesn't seem to be a tar file when I do ls in the directory. It seems like it is a text file. May be once the full  split is completed it will look like a tar file?

Answer (score 3):

The behavior from split is correct, from man page online: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html

> Output pieces of FILE to PREFIXaa, PREFIXab, ...

Don't stop the command let it run and then you can use `cat` to concatenate (join) them all back again.

Examples can be seen here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24630/whats-the-best-way-to-join-files-again-after-splitting-them

```
split -b 100m myImage.iso
# later
cat x* > myImage.iso
```

**UPDATE**
Just as clarification since I believe you have not understood the approach. You split a big file like this to transport it for example, files are not usable this way. To use it again you need to concatenate (join) pieces back. If you want usable parts, then you need to decompress the file, split it in parts and compress them. With split you basically **split** the binary file. I don't think you can use those parts.

Comment: Sorry i am new to  this. So in layman's term if i let my command run and then do cat Testfile.taraa > Testfile2.tar this will give me my 2nd split file which is 1tb? What happens to  my original file? I wanted to converted the original file into 2 parts. Does the size of the file reduces?

Comment: @mywayz After having two files, you must join citing them together: *cat Testfile.taraa testfile.tarab > Testfile2.tar*. But you can compress things with gzip if you want to reduce size.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the compression first and the partition later.

If you want each part to be a tar file, you should use 'split' first with de original file, and then 'tar' with each part.

Comment: but my file is already .tar. Is there no way i can just divide the file into two tar files from that?

Comment: @mywayz for creating two tar files from file.tar, you must extract file.tar. There is no other way.